# Unix one liner: Combine 2 headed files

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

If I have 2 files where the first lines contain identical headings:

A.txt:

```
A
1
aa
```

B.txt

```
A
ee
7
```

I want to combine them like so:

C.txt

```
A
1
aa
ee
7
```

Is there a one liner to do this?

Comment: Do you want this to happen *only* if the header is the same?

Comment: Not necessary.. I'm thinking of a simple case when I know the headers are the same. Handling the case where the headers can be slightly different might be the subject of another question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tail -n +2 B.txt | cat A.txt - > C.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If order is not a problem:

sort A.txt B.txt  | uniq

Comment: How will this result in the desired output?

Comment: This also deletes duplicate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that's easily scalable to any number of input files (just add them as additional arguments:

```
awk 'FNR!=NR&&FNR==1{next}{print}' A.txt B.txt > C.txt
```